# Laravel 5.4 blades and select2 not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jquery-select2, laravel-5.4

I have some hard time to make select2 js lib working in laravel, there are no errors in console. My blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dodaj nowy podmiot</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div >
                        <div>
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="js-example-basic-single">
                                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
</script>
@endsection
```

It only changes CSS of the item, but select even if it's clickable nothing happens, it doesn't show options, dropdown is not appearing.

Has anyone faced issues like that before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, I have resolved this problem by commenting this line in my layout blade:

```
<!-- <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> !-->
```

so, the default js file included in laravel is causing the problem with select2 library.

Thanks for help

Comment: I will :). Need to wait 18 hours until I will be able to accept it.

Comment: Is there any solution without commenting the app.js because we have used layout blade in some other pages as well. If we commenting out then the default jquery will not work.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `defer`.

In `app.blade.php` file there is declare like below.

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

Here remove `defer` and make it like

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the select instantiation code inside the ready clause?

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
}
```

EDIT:

You are missing the type="text/javascript" in your javascript imports. Some browsers won't execute JavaScript if it doesn't have that tag. Try to fix that and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but then it's shows that select2 is not a function so I am assuming it's related to the way how laravel renders blades.

Comment: Laravel blade rendering simply creates a string with HTML/JS. It doesn't really influence how your JS gets executed. It's probably because the HTML the browser receives doesn't have a proper jQuery/select2 library import.

Comment: You are missing the type= text/javascript in the script imports. That's what's wrong.

Comment: You're wrong, the 'type="text/javascript"' is optional, the modern web browsers know what to do with <script> //code </script>, only when you will write something like <script type="not_text_javascript"> //code </script> it won't run it like JS. So it's not an issue with that. 
As far as I can see in network tab it loads stuff properly. I have also checked this code by pasting it to the raw html file and it's works properly. So it has to be related with laravel.

Comment: So you are saying that if you somehow copy the HTML, it works but if exactly the same HTML gets provided by Laravel, it won't work? Obviously you must be returning something else from blade than what works when you manually paste raw html. So just compare the difference and fix it because the web browser doesn't care whether the backend is Laravel or Node.js or a bunch of monkeys farting into a plastic pipe. It just cares about the Response it gets.